# Angular 6 AuthGuard

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm just trying to hide menu if the user is not authenticated.
Please, Don't worry about the token, I have not done yet.

What is the problem?
if **isLoggedIn** is true, **!isLoggedIn** should be false, but it doesn't works like that!!

In AppComponentHTML:

```
<app-menu *ngIf="isLoggedIn | async"></app-menu>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!isLoggedIn | async"></router-outlet>
```

app-menu works fine if user is authenticated, but router-outlet doesn't.

Here is the rest of my code below:

AuthGuard:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, CanLoad, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  localStorage;

  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  authenticationHandler(): boolean {
    this.localStorage = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (this.localStorage) {
      this.loggedIn.next(true);
      return true;
    } else {
      this.loggedIn.next(false);
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.authenticationHandler();
  }

  canLoad(): boolean {
    return this.authenticationHandler();
  }
}
```

AppComponentTS:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthGuardService} from './services/auth-guard.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private authGuardService: AuthGuardService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authGuardService.isLoggedIn();
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)"></router-outlet>
```