# Angular 6 auth guard stays on blank page when logged in

Tags: angular, typescript

I found this answer and I'm modifying it work with my authentication: [Angular 6 AuthGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003911/angular-6-authguard)

However, when the user is successfully authenticated, the auth guard just goes to a blank page instead of forwarding to the URL. Note that it works as expected when the user has no token. It forwards to the login page.

I see the console output for the "valid token" line, but the redirect doesn't happen. Also, if I put "return true;" at the top of the handler, the forwarding works.

Here's the code block in question from my auth guard service:

```
authenticationHandler(): boolean {
    if (this.myToken) {
      this._auth.validateToken(this.myToken)
        .subscribe((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            // TODO
            console.log('AuthGuard: valid token');

            this.loggedIn.next(true);
            return true;
          } else {
            this.loggedIn.next(false);
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }

        });
    } else {
      this.loggedIn.next(false);
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.authenticationHandler();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `true` inside the subscribe function, that value doesn't get passed further out to the route guard. Instead the route guard is returning `undefined` which evaluates to `falsey`.

You want the route guard to wait for the token to validate before returning. The simplest way of achieving this is using async/await syntax.

```
async authenticationHandler(): Promise<boolean> {
  if (this.myToken) {
    const result = await this._auth.validateToken(this.myToken).toPromise();
    if (result.value) {
        // TODO
        console.log('AuthGuard: valid token');

        this.loggedIn.next(true);
        return true;
     } else {
        this.loggedIn.next(false);
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
     }

  } else {
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

This way your code will have the validation result before returning out of the route guard.

Comment: thx that's helpful. I'm trying it now, but it's not accepting boolean as a return type for an async function.

Comment: Have it return `Promise<boolean>` rather than `boolean`

Comment: Excellent, yes that works. Thanks!  I also found that it works by changing the lib in tsconfig.json to "lib": [ "es2015", ...